# Error 255 in Xcode 4.5 compiling with LLVM 4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, ios6

I'm trying to compile my project with the latest xcode + sdk 6.0
when the building is almost done, I got this error:

```
2012-09-26 16:52:24.714 ibtoold[5603:b03] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-2840/Framework/Document/IBDocument.m:1514
Details:  Some objects didn't get the ibBeginArchivingDocument:withContext: callback. A class has probably overridden the method without calling through to super.
Object:   <IBCocoaTouchDocument: 0x40072df00>
Method:   -willArchiveWithContext:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a260>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:  0  0x000000010550e44c -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundatio  
1  0x000000010550e2a5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundatio  
2  0x0000000104b35245 -[IBDocument willArchiveWithContext:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  
3  0x00000001086407d6 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  
4  0x0000000108640c3a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  
5  0x0000000104b44745 __47-[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  
6  0x0000000104b5b9a1 -[IBDocument assertIfArbitrationIsScheduledDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  
7  0x0000000104b44710 -[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  
8  0x0000000104a46f90 (in ibtool  
9  0x0000000104a440e8 (in ibtool 
10  0x0000000104a43c5f (in ibtoold 
11  0x0000000104a43b53 (in ibtoold 
12  0x0000000104a50165 (in ibtoold 
13  0x0000000104a43684 (in ibtoold 
14  0x0000000104a448f1 (in ibtoold 
15  0x0000000104a42524 (in ibtoold 
16  0x000000000000000 Command /Applications/Xcode4.5SDK6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Only for a XIB I'll not able to build with success...have you got the solution?
thanks!
Dario

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I edited this a few times as new ideas came to mind so its a bit jerky I know.

1)Look at the command line tool 'ibtool' - there is a man page - and you can try manually to translate the xib file and maybe validate it (I've not used this in years and years)

2) Other ideas (but failing those, you should burn a DTS Incident - you get 2 per year - and try to get some help from an Apple engineer):

- clean your project
- delete the cached data (Organizer->Projects->Derived Data tap 'Delete...'
- insure that for this XIB the proper versioning is set (select XIB, 3rd Xcode tab on right, File options:

[image]

- close the project
- quit Xcode
- reopen Xcode, then the product
- try again

If this does not do it, use the DTS incident, or post on the internal Apple lists - the ones you have to login for - and maybe someone there knows of an issue

3) If you are truly desperate, make a copy of your xib file. Then start deleting objects, the easiest first, and try to build. At some point it may compile. Then re-add the other objects back.

4) If 3 does not do it, blow the xib file away, create a new one, and essentially reconstruct what you have.

EDIT: (update in comments by original poster)

5) Reboot the machine and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot but. I tried the 3rd one and...when i set the "Development" tab to Xcode 4.5, the it crash! why???

Comment: Hmm - look and see if the "auto layout" checkbox is unchecked. Of you set the Development tab to say 4.4 it works? Well, if that's the case then just do that and hope the problem goes away (its what I'd do - along with sending the file to Apple in a bug report). If the autolayout is NOT checked, then do as 3) says and start deleting objects. Then go to 4). I can only guess at the reason, but most likely Apple is compiling he file differently since autolayout MIGHT be checked - and the new xib->nib compiler is choking on something in your file.

Comment: Auto Layout was Unchecked...so i'm trying to follow the 3rd and 4rd methods!thanks so much...

Comment: Once you find the problem please make a comment here or edit your question - to help others who read it later on.

Comment: I had to additionally reboot the machine. Just the above steps did not help.

Answer (score 4):

"Clean" my project solved my problem. I'm using XCode 4.5.

Comment: Yeah, that's an excellent first step whenever encountering some strange error, particularly if you've make some significant change to the project or its environment.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps work for me.

Thanks David for steps #1 to #4

1. Clean my project build
2. Delete the cached data (Organizer->Projects->Derived Data tap 'Delete...'
3. Close the project
4. Quit Xcode (I did stop at this step and tried to reopen Xcode but the error remains)
5. Restart my computer. (Tried to open Xcode afterwards but the same build error still happens)
6. Make a copy of Xcode (I put the copy at ~/Desktop)
7. Delete the original copy at /Applications
8. Put the copy of Xcode back to /Applications
9. Done